# Is there a way to determine if package depends on wine to run from its .deb?

Tags: wine, deb, package-info

I would like to know if installed app will use wine server to run:

for e.g. picasa once installed -- it uses wine to run, however I want to know that picasa will use wine before installing it.

I've tried `dpkg -I` but doesn't show this particular info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it it runs on wine it is an .exe

List the contents of a .deb with `dpkg-deb`

grep (search) for an .exe

```
dpkg-deb -c your.deb | grep exe
```

If you find a .exe , it runs on wine

Comment: What about Mono things? They use `.exe`s so something like Banshee or SpaceChem would be a false positive.

Comment: good point, but I do not think picasa uses mono ... /me goes to check

Comment: This answer seems to work, though I would like more explanation about @Oli's approach

Comment: see `man dpkg-deb` , the -f lists fields , so he is listing the dependencies. You can tell from the dependencies if it is a linux or windows binary.

Answer (score 3):

Well I knew it could be done but it took 10 minutes to work out:

```
dpkg-deb -f package.deb depends
```

**Edit:** This won't work for Picasa because it bundles its own copy of Wine. It's not a dependency. (And that's why the download is 30MB)

Comment: exact output for picasa `wisemonkey@devMachine:~/Ubuntu/ProgInstalls$ dpkg-deb -f picasa_3.0-current_amd64.deb depends
libc6-i386 (>= 2.2), ia32-libs, lib32asound2, lib32z1, gconf2`

`dpkg -I picasa_3.0-current_amd64.deb` outputs

`Architecture: amd64
 Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.2), ia32-libs, lib32asound2, lib32z1, gconf2` 

I'm not sure what shows that it is a wine dependent :(

Comment: @wisemonkey Updated. It won't work for Picasa but it will for things that do have proper dependencies on Wine.

Comment: @Oli - too bad, it was an elegant solution

Comment: @Oli: will keep that in mind :) thats why I asked question if u see `dpkg -I` also lists dependencies